# Accessing static variable through subclass method

Tags: dart

I'm get null returned when attempting to access a subclass static variable through a overridden subclass accessor:

```dart
library resource;

abstract class Resource 
{
  String name;
  String description;
  Resource(this.name, this.description);

  Resource.map(Map data)
  {
    ...
    _getDb()[this] = data;
  }

  abstract Map _getDb();
}

class Skill extends Resource
{
  static Map _skills = {}
  Skill.map(Map data) : super.map(data);

  Map_getDb()
  {
    return _skills;
  }
}

import 'resource.dart'

void main() {
  useVMConfiguration();

  test('constructor', () {

    Skill skill = new Skill.map({
                                  'name': 'foo'
                                  });
  }
}
```

Here I'm trying to call `_getDb()` on the (hopefully) now constructed subclass in the super constructor.  Despite `_skills` being instantiated, `_getDb()` returns null.

Is this possible?

EDIT: 
`_skills` is not present when inspecting `this` at `_getDb()`:

```
this  Skill [id=0]    
  description "bar" [id=19]  
  name  "foo" [id=18]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example has several flaws as DartEditor shows.

`Map_getDb()` is missing a space between `Map` and `_getDb()`.
Is this only in your question or in the code you run too?

`abstract Map _getDb();` is also a syntax error.
In Dart a method is made abstract when you don't provide an implementation (`;` instead of `{}`)

After this fixes the code works fine.

Comment: You are correct: the sample I posted runs without error :-P.  I'll delete this question and run my sample code before posting next time!